# Kotlin Client Generator support for Enum Unknown Values

Tags: kotlin, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm wondering if there is a way to generate a kotlin lib from an openapi spec that will support a default value if it doesn't serialize a known enum value.

Ex: the Java Generator has the `enumUnknownDefaultCase` flag in its [spec](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md#config-options)

Ref from the kotlin generator seems to read in the config for the moshi serializer [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/KotlinClientCodegen.java#L602)

But unable to get this working by specifying the following two options via the kotlin generator:

```
"moshiCodeGen": "true"
"enumUnknownDefaultCase": "true"
```

[Related conversation here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1552#issuecomment-1191661270)

Thanks for any help figuring out how to get kotlin clients to not explode on new enumeration values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `openapi-generator-cli` to generate code, the option `enumUnknownDefaultCase` should working by adding `--additional-properties=enumUnknownDefaultCase=true`

Example:

```bash
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-6.0.0.jar -i "example.com/swagger?format=openapi" -g kotlin --library=jwm-retrofit2 -o my-api-sdk --additional-properties=enumUnknownDefaultCase=true
```

It will create a SerializerHelper class which will add additional enum-adapter to Moshi builder like this

```java
moshiBuilder
  .add(MyEnum::class.java, EnumJsonAdapter.create(MyEnum::class.java).withUnknownFallback(MyEnum.unknown_default_open_api))
  .add(...)
```

But it's not done yet, when initialize your ApiClient, you must force it to use MoshiBuilder with the enum-adapter, by default it won't use that one.

```kotlin
Retrofit.Builder()
   .baseUrl(baseUrl)
   .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
++ .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(Serializer.moshi))
-- .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(serializerBuilder.build()))
   .apply {
      if (converterFactory != null) {
         addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
      }
   }
```